# Making a horizontal line at the high of every red candle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have plenty of experience programming but I have no idea how to accomplish what I want to in Pinescript.

So, what I'm trying to do is plot lines on a weekly timeframe that mark the high of all red candles, so far I've been able to only plot shapes, and while I was able to plot the shapes on the top of the reds, it wasn't exact and hovers above more than I like, while also not showing the price point.

To be honest, I have no code to show here as what I've done so far has been completely unsuccessful in fulfilling what I want to achieve.

Could anyone show me or explain to me how to do this?

Edit: To show better what I'm trying to achieve, here is closest thing I have so far,

```
redCandle = (close < open)
timeFrame = input.timeframe("W", title="Time Frame")

d_h = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeFrame, high[0], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

plot(d_h, style=plot.style_circles, color=color.green, linewidth=2)
```

So this is almost what I'm trying to get, but instead of every single candle, just the red ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `redCandle` to your `security()` call to check out if the weekly candle is red or not.

Then use that return value as a condition to your `plot()` call.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

redCandle = (close < open)
timeFrame = input.timeframe("W", title="Time Frame")

[d_h, d_red] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeFrame, [high, redCandle], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

plot(d_red ? d_h : na, style=plot.style_circles, color=color.green, linewidth=2)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do, I had no idea it was such a simple thing I was missing. Thanks!